# Add extension to CertificateRequestMessage

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to put a custom element (a template name to use for the PKI) in my Certificate request that I generate using bouncycastle library.

The RFC says that you can use an extension that follows :

```
id-regInfo-utf8Pairs    OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-regInfo 1 }
--with syntax UTF8Pairs ::= UTF8String
```

The few lines of code concerning this are

```
CertificateRequestMessageBuilder msgbuilder = new
                CertificateRequestMessageBuilder(BigInteger.valueOf(reqId));
        msgbuilder.addExtension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.7.5.2.1"),  false, ???);
```

I can't find any information on what to put in that addExtension function, nor any example to adapt from.

I guess the `new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.7.5.2.1")` is close to what is expected, but the following ASN1Encodable that is supposed to be the value of that field is a mystery to me.

I just want to get something along `template:encipherment` in that field.

This seems like a pretty simple thing to do but the lack of documentation coupled to my lack of experience with BouncyCastle causes me a lot of problems.

The questions are :

Am I doing what I want the correct way ? (Using the extensions of the CRMF to convey my custom field)

If I do, how do I make this work ?